# Emachines 5230 will not start up

Tags: hardware-failure

I cannot find a bleep code for the machine model, the original manual at manualowl does not have it.

I have cleaned the inside, checked the Ram fits, checked there are no lose wires.

when i press power button, there is power but after 10 seconds there is like a siren bleeping pattern noise, incessantly - nee, nor, nee, nor...

and thats it

user claims it was working perfectly before he shipped it to me as ebay transaction.

Comment: It sounds like something mechanical. The first suspect would be the disk which could have taken a hit during transport. If it is a WD or Seagate disk, they have tools (e.g. Seatools) that can check the health of the disk.

Comment: ask for a refund, it arrived DOA and you are not responsible for that, the seller is, don't waste time get a refund.